# Why it throws ClassCastException: char[] cannot be cast to android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

Here below are the exception logs:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: char[] cannot be cast to android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl
at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:358)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:171)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:171)
at com.android.internal.telephony.cat.CatService.saveCmdToPreference(CatService.java:2632)
at com.android.internal.telephony.cat.CatService.handleDBHandler(CatService.java:2079)
at com.android.internal.telephony.cat.CatService.handleMessage(CatService.java:1841)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Loo|debug info:dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)|java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)|java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:522)|com.letv.bsp.crashhandler.utils.LogUtils.trace(LogUtils.java:86)|com.letv.bsp.crashhandler.CrashHandleService.reportException(CrashHandleService.java:915)|com.letv.bsp.crashhandler.CrashHandleService.onStartCommand(CrashHandleService.java:663)|android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3291)|android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)|android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1674)|android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)|android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)|android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5905)|java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)|com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)|com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)|, blk: false printBlacklist the current black list :
```

And here below are the codes exception throws at  android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences

```
    @Override
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode) {
    SharedPreferencesImpl sp;
    synchronized (ContextImpl.class) {
        if (sSharedPrefs == null) {
            sSharedPrefs = new ArrayMap<String, ArrayMap<String, SharedPreferencesImpl>>();
        }

        final String packageName = getPackageName();
        ArrayMap<String, SharedPreferencesImpl> packagePrefs = sSharedPrefs.get(packageName);
        if (packagePrefs == null) {
            packagePrefs = new ArrayMap<String, SharedPreferencesImpl>();
            sSharedPrefs.put(packageName, packagePrefs);
        }

        // At least one application in the world actually passes in a null
        // name.  This happened to work because when we generated the file name
        // we would stringify it to "null.xml".  Nice.
        if (mPackageInfo.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion <
                Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (name == null) {
                name = "null";
            } // here is the line 358
        }

        sp = packagePrefs.get(name);
        if (sp == null) {
            File prefsFile = getSharedPrefsFile(name);
            sp = new SharedPreferencesImpl(prefsFile, mode);
            packagePrefs.put(name, sp);
            return sp;
        }
    }
    if ((mode & Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS) != 0 ||
        getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // If somebody else (some other process) changed the prefs
        // file behind our back, we reload it.  This has been the
        // historical (if undocumented) behavior.
        sp.startReloadIfChangedUnexpectedly();
    }
    return sp;
}
```

Let's suppose the log information is correct, and it should be correct almost.

My first question is: what does it mean by saying that throws cast exception at line 358 at ContextImpl.java file? There is only a right brace there.

I guess the statement below line 358 is the root case of the exception

```
sp = packagePrefs.get(name);
```

because sp is declare as SharedPreferencesImpl, and it should have a cast operation when the get method return and assignment, if the value return is a char[], then the cast exception should throw, this explanation is very reasonable. But the value in packagePrefs has parameterized  as SharedPreferencesImpl once declare at

```
packagePrefs = new ArrayMap<String, SharedPreferencesImpl>();
```

Therefore, it should have no chance to put a value type of char[] into packagePrefs. Then, I am confused again, where is the code occur this exception and why.

There is another similar problem, the log is:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: char[] cannot be cast to              com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$LogRec
at com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$LogRecords.add(StateMachine.java:665)
at com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.performTransitions(StateMachine.java:830)
at com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:801)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

And the corresponding codes is at com.android.internal.util.StateMachine.LogRecords:

```
        private Vector<LogRec> mLogRecVector = new Vector<LogRec>();
        synchronized void add(StateMachine sm, Message msg, String messageInfo, IState state,
            IState orgState, IState transToState) {
        mCount += 1;
        if (mLogRecVector.size() < mMaxSize) {
            mLogRecVector.add(new LogRec(sm, msg, messageInfo, state, orgState, transToState));
        } else {
            LogRec pmi = mLogRecVector.get(mOldestIndex);
            mOldestIndex += 1;
            if (mOldestIndex >= mMaxSize) {
                mOldestIndex = 0;
            }
            pmi.update(sm, msg, messageInfo, state, orgState, transToState);
        }
    }
```

It both seems to be a problem about generic. Hope help from experts here and thanks so much in advance.

Comment: What package and class is the method `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)`? You have two methods by that name in the stack trace, with different packages.  Are you absolutely ***sure*** you've shown us the correct method?

Comment: The method is at android.app.ContextImpl class, I have updated. And how can you know there are two methods by that name in the stack trace, with different packages? Can you explain for me clearly? Maybe the root case is using the wrong class in the other package.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe some other code path could be inserting `char[]` objects into these data structures (e.g. you're using `char[]` objects elsewhere and storing them in similar places)?

Comment: No, that can't be true, since it is a local variable and is parameterized when declare. The only possibility that put char[] value into map successfully only if it is raw type generic.

Answer (score 0):

To the first issue (that the line number doesn't correspond to the error) my guess is you added three lines (perhaps the `name = "null"` conditional) since last compiling. Any time you see stack traces that don't seem to line-up that's a strong hint that your source and your binary are out of sync.

For the second issue that we shouldn't see a `ClassCastException` because `packagePrefs` and `mLogRecVector` are generic, I'd agree this seems impossible if your code snippets compile (you might run into issues if `sSharedPrefs` were a raw type, but I'm assuming that's not the case). My first theory would be that you need to re-build (going off of the hint that the stack trace doesn't line up with your source code).

If a full rebuild doesn't work I'd have to assume this is an Android-specific issue (perhaps you're using ProGuard?). Are you able to replicate this in OracleJDK or OpenJDK? If you can create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can replicate the issue with it would help get to the bottom of this.

Comment: To the first issue, you are correct, I misunderstand the meaning of the date information from version code provided by tester. Line 358 point to sp = packagePrefs.get(name); after source code is consistent with binary. And this method never have changed since it was created.

This issue is occur at user's cellular phone, it happen casually, and we can't replicate it.

Comment: I'm not sure how much help we can be if it can't be replicated. Is there anything strange about their phone, e.g. running an old version of Android?